# SetConsoleCursorPosition not working correctly in C: characters get printed at random locations

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I'm trying to make a simple console game engine, capable of displaying char arrays at specified locations. For now, everything is working correctly, but the console doesn't want to cooperate:

I use SetConsoleCursorPosition function (from `Windows.h`) in order to set correct location in console, and `putchar()` in order to print characters one by one (I have also tested `putc()`, `fputc()` and `_putch()`, but it didn't help)

For testing I've set up simple program. In `GraphicsEngine.h`:

```
void setCoordinates(int x, int y) {
    COORD cursorPos;
    cursorPos.X = x;
    cursorPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cursorPos);
}

void printObject(const unsigned char* object, int x, int y, int* xOld, int* yOld) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    *xOld = x;
    *yOld = y;
    while (object[i] != '\t') {
        putchar(object[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (object[i] == '\n') { //if approached newline, travel one line down
            y++;
            setCoordinates(x, y);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

In `main.c`:

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 10;
    int xOld = 0;
    int yOld = 0;
    setCoordinates(x, y);
    printObject(ship, x, y, &xOld, &yOld, true);
```

The array that I pass to `printObject()` function:

```
const unsigned char ship[] = 
{
32,32,64,'\n',
32,47,'#',92,'\n',
174,'#','#','#',175,'\n','\t'
};
```

Giving, for example, x = 20 and y = 20 the code seems to print the ship correctly:
[image: seems good]

But often (randomly, sometimes every time, sometimes every 10 launches) the printed array is totally out of order:

[image: seems bad]

It's a big issue because I want to make a game allowing player movement on a 2D plane (in x axis and y axis) and while refreshing the screen many times, some characters are glitching a bit.

Comment: It was my mistake while copying fragments of code into the question, I have `setCoordinates(x, y)` in real code

Comment: You should provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, a small but complete code example that anyone can run to reproduce the problem. For example, is there any threading in other parts of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread lacks code that can reproduce the problem. I modified your code and added part of the code, now it should meet your needs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

const unsigned char ship[] =
{
32,32,64,'\n',
32,47,'#',92,'\n',
174,'#','#','#',175,'\n','\t'
};

const unsigned char ship_remove[] =
{
32,32,32,'\n',
32,32,32,32,'\n',
32,32,32,32,32,'\n','\t'
};

void hidecursor()
{
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO info;
    info.dwSize = 100;
    info.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(consoleHandle, &info);
}

void setCoordinates(int x, int y) {
    COORD cursorPos;
    cursorPos.X = x;
    cursorPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cursorPos);
}

void printObject(const unsigned char* object, int x, int y, int *xOld, int *yOld) {

    int i = 0;
    *xOld = x;
    *yOld = y;
    while (object[i] != '\t') {
        char r = object[i];
        putchar(object[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (object[i] == '\n') { //if approached newline, travel one line down
            y++;
            setCoordinates(x, y);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void clear(const unsigned char* object, int x, int y)
{
    setCoordinates(x, y);
    int i = 0;
    while (object[i] != '\t') {
        char r = object[i];
        putchar(object[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (object[i] == '\n') { //if approached newline, travel one line down
            y++;
            setCoordinates(x, y);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{  
    hidecursor();
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    int xOld = 0;
    int yOld = 0;
    setCoordinates(x, y);
    printObject(ship, x, y, &xOld, &yOld);
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x41) & 0x0001)
        {           
            clear(ship_remove, xOld, yOld);
            x = xOld;
            y = yOld;
            setCoordinates(x - 1, y);
            printObject(ship, x - 1, y, &xOld, &yOld);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x44) & 0x0001)
        {
            clear(ship_remove, xOld, yOld);
            x = xOld;
            y = yOld;
            setCoordinates(x + 1, y);
            printObject(ship, x + 1, y, &xOld, &yOld);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) & 0x0001)
        {
            clear(ship_remove, xOld, yOld);
            x = xOld;
            y = yOld;
            setCoordinates(x, y - 1);
            printObject(ship, x, y - 1, &xOld, &yOld);
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x53) & 0x0001)
        {
            clear(ship_remove, xOld, yOld);
            x = xOld;
            y = yOld;
            setCoordinates(x, y + 1 );
            printObject(ship, x, y + 1, &xOld, &yOld);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Operation: 'A'  ←  'D'  →  'W'  ↑  'S'  ↓

Debug:

[image: 1]

Comment: It's not clear why you decided to post an answer after having verified that the question isn't answerable.